# Change column title name in WP admin for custom post types

Tags: php, wordpress

I created 2 custom post types, Staff and Movies. Trying to change the title column name for both custom post types in one code snippet but can't figure it out. This is what I have so far:

```
function change_column_name( $columns ) {
    $screen = get_current_screen();
  
    if ( 'staff' == $screen -> post_type ) {
        $columns['title'] = 'Staff Name';
    }
    elseif ( 'movies' == $screen -> post_type ) {
        $columns['title'] = 'Movie Title';
    }
  
    return $columns;
}

add_filter( 'manage_' . $screen -> post_type . '_posts_columns', 'change_column_name' );
```

This is the title that I am trying to change:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by ""column title" - are you referring to something in the WP admin, or somewhere you display it on your site?

Comment: [This is what I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NH3eU.png).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to access the `$screen` variable here:

```
add_filter( 'manage_' . $screen -> post_type . '_posts_columns', 'change_column_name' );
```

...but this outside of your `change_column_name` function  where you set it up so it doesn't exist when you are trying to use it for your `add_filter.`

You could add the custom post types directly into the `manage_XXX_posts_columns` like this:

```
add_filter( 'manage_staff_posts_columns', 'change_column_name' );
add_filter( 'manage_movies_posts_columns', 'change_column_name' );
```

However, there is no need to do this for every CPT you want to change - you can hook into the default `manage_posts_columns` which will run for all posts even CPTs:

```
add_filter( 'manage_posts_columns', 'change_column_name' );
```

You just need to check for the CPT in your function and only change those titles - and you are already doing that, so you don't need to change anything in your function to do it this way.